# Write an array response from servlet to JavaScript?

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, printwriter

I am trying to write a single Array object using `PrintWriter.out.write()` as a response to a JavaScript (AJAX) function,
Is this possible? or will I need to convert the array in same manner before sending?
Trying to avoid creation of comma separated String and then parsing in JS

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.write(listDir());
}


private File[] listDir(){

    File folder = new File("/home/rob/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    //System.out.println("Number of files found: " + listOfFiles.length);

    return listOfFiles;
}
```

Would like to then iterate through the files within the calling JavaScript AJAX function:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

    for (var i = 0; i < xmlhttp.responseText.length; i++) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText[i]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Since you don't want to make your response from the Servlet in Text format, you will have to convert the result to JSON format, you could check a good example in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/2727401

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's array objects don't have an implementation of `toString()` method. As such, your output  from

```
out.write(listDir());
```

will look something like

```
[Ljava.io.File;@5d9d277e
```

You definitely don't want this. There are many ways to serialize arrays. One of these is to separate the elements by `,`

```
out.write(Arrays.toString(listDir()));
```

gives you something like

```
[some.txt, other.png]
```

Other formats include JSON and XML. Since Javascript comes with a built-in JSON parser, I would suggest you use JSON. You can find a Java JSON library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library). Change the content-type if you return something like JSON (ex. `application/json`).